# SwiftUI - NavigationBarTitleDisplayMode - Change title dynamically based on mode

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Is there a way to get notified when the .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode (which is set to .automatic) of a view changes from .large to .inline or vice versa?

Something like an @Environment object similar to

```
@Environment(\.locale) var locale: Locale
```

Depending on the displayMode, I'd like to show a different title.
Something along the lines of:

```
@Environment(\.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode) var mode: NavigationBarTitleDisplayMode

...

.navigationBarTitle(mode == .large ? "I am the large title" : "Inline title")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
```

Comment: can't do with SwiftUI. You would have to dig into UIKit > https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/3198027-scrolledgeappearance

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by creating your own parameter.

```
@State private var mode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode = .large
(...)
.navigationBarTitle(mode == .large ? "I am the large title" : "Inline title")
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(mode)
```

You can pass this var into the environment and have a global indicator.